# Netbeans Code Assistance C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, windows-8, code-assist

I'd like to activate the Netbeans Code Assistance but for C++, I just installed Netbeans 8.0 and followed all the steps in Netbeans site for installing Cygwing compiler. I am now able to compile C++ code; however the facility of Code Assistance doesn't appear. I don't know how to activate it.

Comment: First hit on Google: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/HowTos.html

Comment: Doesnt work. It says is for projects from existing sources or existing binary, and, for the others projects (like mine) "configuration" is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Code assistance should be active by default. Make sure your project properties aren't screwed up:

[image: Project Properties Pop-up Window]

Also you might need to add include directories in the Netbeans global options, which are in the "Tools" submenu for my Netbeans version:

[image: Global Options]